# Passing an implicit to a playframework JSON Reads

Tags: json, playframework-2.0, implicit

I would like to know whats the best way to pass an implicit to a Playframework Json Reader/Writer

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.html

In other words I would like to be able to do something like :

```
def reads(json: JsValue)(implicit configuration: TenantConfiguration): JsResult[User]
```

But I can't do it this way since the Reads trait doesn't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change Reads[T], it's clear.
I would simply create my own reads function such as?

```
def customReads[T](json:JsValue)(implicit reads: Reads[T], configuration: TenantConfiguration): JsResult[T] = ...
```